# Calculate Curvature from an Image

Tags: image-processing, smoothing, curve, edge-detection

I would like to calculate the curvature of the white line in the attached figure. And there are two questions I would like to seek for some help:

1. Before I start to calculate the curvature, I suspect I need to smooth the edge of the white line to get a better result. How should I do that and maintain the curvature of the line at the same time?
2. How should I calculate the curvature based on an image like the attached one?

I am open to both Python and MATLAB solutions. Thank you very much for any advice.

[image]

Comment: Take a look here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html.  I'd probably find contours on the blob to get the polygon of its contour, and then do some kind of curve fit on those vertices.